# How to print some of the pages of an Excel sheet in PDF?

Tags: excel, vba

I have adjusted my sheet in Page Layout and have 10 pages in total.

I would like to export some of them as a PDF, for example 1, 2, 5, 8 and 10.

Comment: This is possible with the `Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` method (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat)). It has the option to set a "start page" and "end page" and exports the specified pages to PDF.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. But here I have from and to. How can I choose specific pages like 2,5,8?

Comment: Check the answer I posted...

Comment: You can set up multiple print areas per sheet, so if you know which ranges you want printed, you can restrict the print area to only those

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` method:

```
Sub ExportPages()
    Dim MyWorksheet as Worksheet
    Set MyWorksheet = Application.Workbooks("NameOfYourWorkbook").Worksheets("NameOfYourWorksheet")

    ' This will save pages 1 and 2 in the file "Pages 1 and 2.pdf" in the current folder
    MyWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="Pages 1 and 2", From:=1, To:=2
    ' Repeat this as often as you want setting different values to the options From:= and To:=

    Set MyWorksheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

To save specific pages like 2, 5 and 7 just call the method multiple times:

```
MyWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="Page 2", From:=2, To:=2
MyWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="Page 5", From:=5, To:=5
MyWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="Page 7", From:=7, To:=7
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. But won't that save me 3 pdfs instead of one?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, I misunderstood what you meant... A solution for this might be to create a new Worksheet, copy the required pages into the new Worksheet and then export from the new Worksheet. All of this can be done via VBA.